# Proving $f$ is a real, uniformly continuous function on the bounded subset $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^1 \implies f$ is bounded on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, solution-verification

(Baby Rudin Chapter 4 Exercise 8)

I am trying to prove:

> $f$ is a real, uniformly continuous function on the bounded subset $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^1 \implies f$ is bounded on $E$.

**My attempt**:

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $f$ is a real, uniformly continuous function on $E$. For a contradiction, assume $f$ is not bounded on $E$. Then there exists a non-finite $f(p)$ for some $p \in E$. Let $r\in E$ be distinct from $p$. The boundedness of $E$ guarantees the existence of the real number $M$ such that $|p-r|< M$. Due to the usual properties of the absolute value function (and $p\ne r$), we conclude that $0<|p-r|<M$, that is, $M$ is positive. By the definition of uniform continuity,
\begin{equation}\tag{8.1}
    |p-r|<M \implies |f(p)-f(r)| <\epsilon
\end{equation}
for some $\epsilon>0$. (We utilize the uniform continuity of $f$ in asserting that the $\delta$ in (8.1) would hold for our choice of $p$, given an arbitrary $r \in E$.) Note that the consequent (8.1) births a contradiction since the absolute difference of the non-finite $f(p)$ and $f(x)$ cannot be made smaller than $\epsilon$.

**My question**: Is my proof correct in general? In particular, I am not sure if I should have taken $r \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of taking $r \in E$ above. The issue is that the definition of a bounded set mandates that $r$ be some real number (not necessarily in $E$) and the definition of uniform continuity requires that $r$ be in $E$. Is my proof totally incorrect? Can someone suggest how this proof can be improved / completed?

Definition of a bounded set:

> Let $X$ be a metric space. $E$ is bounded if there is a real number $M$ and a point $q \in X$ such that $d(p, q)<M$ for all $p \in E$.

Definition of uniform continuity:

> Let $f$ be a mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$. We say that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $d_Y(f(p), f(q))$ for all $p$ and $q$ in $X$ for which $d_X(p, q)<\delta$.

Comment: A real valued function cannot be 'non-finite' at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is not bounded there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$ such that $|f(x_n)|\to \infty$. Since $E$ is bounded so is the sequence $(x_n)$. Hence there is  a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_i})$. Note that $|x_{n_i}-x_{n_j}| \to 0$ as $i,j \to \infty$. Now use the definition of uniform continuity to show that $|f(x_{n_i})-f(x_{n_j})| \to 0$ as $i,j \to \infty$. But then  $(f(x_{n_i}))$ is Cauchy sequence. Any Cauchy sequence of real numbers is convergent, hence bounded. We have arrived at a  contradiction to the fact that $|f(x_{n_i})|\to \infty$.

Comment: If $f(x_{n_i})$ is bounded, then how do we have a contradiction? Divergent sequences can have convergent sub-sequences, right?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson $|f(x_n)| \to \infty$ implies that $|f(x_{n_i})| \to \infty$. How can we have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: What if $|f(x_n)|=\{0, 1, 0, 1, \dots\}$ and $|f(x_{n_i})|=\{0, 0, 0, \dots\}$? We have no contradiction at all then.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Are you saying that $\{0,1,0,1...\}$ tends to $\infty$? I am starting with  the assumption that $f$ is **not bounded** so I can choose $(x_n)$ such that $|f(x_n) | \to \infty$. You make no sense to me.  Please read my proof carefully.

Comment: "Hence there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_i})$".  The limit may be outside $E$, since $E$ is not closed, but that does not present a problem, because we never apply the function to the _limit_, only to individual $x_{n_i}$.  Can you confirm that's correct? (I think this is a detail worth spelling out.)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a function $f$ is uniform continuous on a bounded domain $E$ , then at all limit points of the domain $E$, limit of $f$ exists finitely.

Now, as , $E$ is bounded, all of it's limit points are of finite value. And , since, $limf$ exists at each limit points, so , $f$ must bounded on $E$.
By the theorem, existance of $limf$ on $\bar E $ $\implies $ $f$ is bounded on $E$